# Clustering and coordinate rotation

Tags: clustering, rotation

Does the coordinate system rotation affect the clustering result?

Which approach could be used to eliminate the influence of coordinate system rotation in clustering?

Any help would be appreciated！

Answer (score 1):

It depends.

Coordinate rotation preserves euclidean-distances ([here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2380741/why-does-rotation-preserve-angles-and-distance-in-the-euclidean-plane)), therefore it won't affect clustering methods based on that, such as k-means or Partitioning around Medoids (PAM) or hierarchical clustering.

For instance, see the nice image below I extracted from [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/the-5-clustering-algorithms-data-scientists-need-to-know-a36d136ef68) web page, where the author compares the results of different clustering algorithms on a set of data structures. If you rotate the matrix of any of these 2-dimensional datasets (2 dimensions is just an example but it could be any number of dimensions) the structure of the data and distances among them would remain the same.
[image]

**Warning**: some of your data might include categorical or ordinal variables, so a rotation in general would not make sense unless you specify a specific metric. For example if you can apply a rotation to your data using a mixed PCA for both continuous and categorical variables, such as the one implemented in the R package `PCAmixdata`. Then, if you apply a k-means to the principal components obtained, you won't get the same results as if you applied it on the original data because the structure of your data has changed. Moreover, you would still have to choose a proper [alternative](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/22/k-means-clustering-for-mixed-numeric-and-categorical-data) k-means that allows categorical variables).

Comment: The last sentence before the image is incomplete.